# Yaws as Rebar dependency

Tags: erlang, yaws, rebar

How can I install Yaws as a Rebar dependency in my Erlang application?

Thanks,

LRP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure you're using a recent version of `rebar`, say from April 2012 or later (`rebar` commit `dc472b` or later), as changes to it were made in early 2012 specifically to support projects like Yaws.

To use Yaws as a dependency, specify the following in your `rebar.config` file:

```
{deps, [{yaws, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/klacke/yaws", {branch, "master"}}}]}.
```

You can replace the `{branch, "master"}` part with a specific Yaws tag if you like:

```
{deps, [{yaws, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/klacke/yaws", {tag, "yaws-1.94"}}}]}.
```

Note, though, that I don't recommend using a version lower than Yaws 1.94 due to changes made to Yaws specifically for `rebar` build support.

How you actually run Yaws depends on how your app uses it. Using it in [an embedded fashion](http://yaws.hyber.org/embed.yaws) is probably best for rebar-built apps, since that way you won't have any dependencies on `yaws.conf` files. But if you want to run Yaws as a stand-alone web server, you can build your dependencies and your application and then [run Yaws interactively](http://yaws.hyber.org/yman.yaws?page=yaws) like this:

```
rebar get-deps compile
./deps/yaws/bin/yaws -i -pa ebin
```

This uses the default `yaws.conf` file found in `./deps/yaws/etc/yaws/yaws.conf`, which you can modify as needed. Starting Yaws in this fashion won't include the `ebin` directories of any other of your application's rebar dependencies in the load path, but you can either add the necessary paths using additional `-pa` options to Yaws, or by [specifying them in the `yaws.conf` file](http://yaws.hyber.org/yman.yaws?page=yaws.conf).

Comment: Being rather spoiled with the automatics of rebar lately, I want to make use embedded yaws , so I added the requirement of yaws-1.99 to rebar config. There are a lot of strange complaints, for example, duplicate .src file. Also, do I need to do further magic inside the deps/yaws dir, for example getting complaints like "Can't exec "libtoolize": No such file or directory at /usr/bin/autoreconf line 196."

Comment: @mattias: are you trying to run `make` to build Yaws? Yaws supports both autotools and rebar, but there's no `make` target for rebar. You need to run `rebar compile` directly to build Yaws with rebar.

Comment: My initial first attempt was just to add the yaws ref to my rebar.config and run rebar get-deps. That didn't work for me. Then I tried some other ways. Should it have been so simple?

Comment: Yes, it should be that simple. Just to be sure, I just set up a simple application with Yaws as a dep, ran `rebar get-deps compile`, and it downloaded `yaws-1.99` and built it, no problem. Running `rebar --version` shows `rebar 2.5.1 R14B04 20141216_212600 git 2.5.1-57-gb796065`. This is specifically built from git version `b796065` from early Dec 2014 because currently (as of 18 Jan 2015) versions newer than that don't work with Yaws.

Comment: Ok, I will try with that version of rebar, I have tried with an old 2.0.?? version and "rebar 2.5.1 17 20150118_115522 git 2.5.1-102-g25aca7e
". Good to hear that it should be that simple.

Comment: Yes, with that particular version of rebar, I can compile yaws 1.99

Comment: Great! Note also that `rebar` master at github as of commit 930d2c7 (from 25 Jan 2015) has fixed the bug I alluded to in my earlier comment.